# logstash - cannot install filters

Tags: logstash

I have below issue,
I have installed newest logstash  7.16.3 and in my corporate environment I spotted that cannot install some filters.

```
./logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-elapsed
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
warning: no jvm.options file found
ERROR: Something went wrong when installing logstash-filter-elapsed, message: Socket closed
```

I think that there can be related with some ports closed.
Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Can't remember the precise github issue, but I read a thread about similar problems when behind corporate firewalls/proxies, as I had the same problem. Something similar https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5902

Comment: hello, thanks for the update, I think that the best way will be install this plugin offline. DO You know if there are some repos where I can find plugins for logstash ?

Comment: I don't know sorry. Better ask on Slack.

Comment: If you need to install it offline, you can generate a pack with everything the plugin needs, you just need a machine with internet connection and to [follow the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/offline-plugins.html#building-offline-packs) on how to generate an offline pack.

Comment: found the issue, read the long timroes comment which is quite interesting https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/20965